# How can I change sonarqube work path from default

Tags: sonarqube, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have a GKE cluster with deployed SonarQube.
Also, we added istio, and changed the work path from http://IP_ADDRESS to http://IP_ADDRESS/sonarqube/.

Now we get an error, because sonarqube tries to find general files in http://IP_ADDRESS, but should check in http://IP_ADDRESS/sonarqube/.

We use https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sonarqube for deployment.
How can I change the work path, which value should I change?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Added:
livenessProbe:
sonarWebContext: /sonarqube/
readinessProbe:
sonarWebContext: /sonarqube/
extraEnv:
sonar.web.context: /sonarqube

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this properties: `sonar.web.host`.